# matplotlib plot of complex valued function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

In matlab plot of a complex vector will result in a plot of imaginary vs real part.

Is there an equivalent function in matplotlib?

Obviously this will work:

```
def plotcomplex(c, *args):
    plot(real(c), imag(c), args)
```

but does it already exist?

Comment: What more do you think to gain? The solution you ost yourself is exactly what you need right?

Comment: I don't think so. What is wrong with your solution?

Comment: my only comment in that you'll want to unpack `*args` and `**kwargs` and you'll want to return the list of artists it produces, e.g., `return plot(real(c), imag(c), *args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no native complex numbers plotting function. Build your own.

Answer (score 7):

Only slightly related, but you can use [cplot](https://github.com/nschloe/cplot) (a project of mine) to plot complex-valued functions using [domain coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring), e.g.,

```py
import cplot
import numpy as np

cplot.show(np.sin, (-5.0, +5.0, 100), (-5.0, +5.0, 100))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I looked into this myself, since it can be a touch inconvenient to split a vector (array) output from a function into real and imaginary parts for the plot function. For example, `f(x).real, f(x).imag` would call the function twice. The closest I've got is to convert the complex vector into an ordered-real vector with the numpy "view" method, return that from the function, and then unpack it with "*" in the plot function. This example for plotting hypercardioid patterns on the complex plane illustrates the technique:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def z(n):
  t = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 1000)
  c = 0.25 * n
  for n in range(1,n+1):
      c = c - (-1) ** n * np.exp(1j * n * t) / (2 * n)
  return c.view('(2,)float').T

plt.plot( *z(2), *z(3), *z(4), *z(5), *z(6), '-', lw=3 )
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

[image: Hypercardioid Patterns]

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Dave Rove's answer to gmpy2 (with great thanks to him):

```
def z(r):
    t = np.linspace(0, 30.0, 1000)
    N = len(t)
    cr = [gmpy2.mpfr(0) for x in range(N)]
    ci = [gmpy2.mpfr(0) for x in range(N)]
    for i in range(N):
        c = <some complex func(r)>
        cr[i] = c.real
        ci[i] = c.imag
    
    return [cr, ci]

def main(argv):
    gmpy2.get_context().precision = 200
    gmpy2.get_context().allow_complex = True
    
    plt.close('all')
    f1 = plt.figure(0)
    f1.clf()
    plt.plot( *z(gmpy2.mpc(9+8.8j)), \
              *z(gmpy2.mpc(9.9+2.1j)), '-', lw=1 )
    plt.axis('scaled')
    plt.show()
```